# Getting error after settings paths in tsconfig file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths, tsconfig.json

Hi React native peoples.
I've added paths to `tsconfig.json` and getting now errors:

` BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module @store/store from /Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/App.tsx: @store/store could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
5 | import { WHITE } from '@uiLibrary/colors';
6 | import { RootNavigator } from '@navigator/RootNavigator';

> 7 | import { store } from '@store/store';
> |                        ^
> 8 |
> 9 | function App(): ReactElement {
> 10 |   return (
> at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
> at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
> at Object.resolve (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21)
> at Graph._resolveDependencies (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:473:35)
> at Graph._processModule (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:261:38)
> at async Graph._addDependency (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:372:20)
> at async Promise.all (index 2)
> at async Graph._processModule (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:322:5)
> at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/mi025n/Home/myapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:249:5)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)

`

In image you can see the project structure.

And here is the tsconfig.json

`{
"compilerOptions": {
"useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
/* Basic Options */
"target": "esnext" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
"module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
"lib": [
"es2017"
] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
"allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
// "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
"jsx": "react-native" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
// "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
// "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.Appointments' file. */
// "outFile": "./",                         /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
//     "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
//     "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
// "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
"noEmit": true /* Do not emit outputs. */,
// "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
// "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
// "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
"isolatedModules": true /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */,

```
/* Strict Type-Checking Options */
"strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
// "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
// "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
// "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
// "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
// "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
// "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

/* Additional Checks */
// "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
// "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
// "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
// "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

/* Module Resolution Options */
"moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
"baseUrl": ".",                        /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
"paths": {
  "@components/*": ["src/common/*"],
  "@store/*": ["src/store/*"],
  "@navigator/*": ["src/navigator/*"],
  "@uiLibrary/*": ["src/uiLibrary/*"]
},
// "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
// "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
// "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
"esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
// "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
"skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
"resolveJsonModule": true /* Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. */

/* Source MapScreen Options */
// "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
// "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate Appointments files instead of generated locations. */
// "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
// "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

/* Experimental Options */
// "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
// "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
```

},
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"babel.config.js",
"metro.config.js",
"jest.config.js",
"**tests**/**/*-test.ts"
]
}
`

Tried to run npm run start --reset-cache.
tried to invalidate caches.

Maybe I need to do something more to use paths?
Maybe need to configure somthing ?